# Singularities in affine and projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Sorry to bother you guys I am trying to read a text that is a bit out of my league. I am doing some of the problems in the book to understand it better. Specifically the singularities and the tangent lines of the polynomial $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$

$p(x,y)=y^3-y^2+x^3-x^2+3y^2x+3x^2y+2xy$

So a singular point would be (a,b) such that the polynomial and the first partial derivatives would be zero. I can see that (0,0) is clearly a singularity and the tangent line corresponding to $\sum _{i+j=m}\frac{\partial P(0,0)}{\partial x^i \partial y^j}$ and factoring that polynomial into linear factors.

Thus I look into the lowest order terms $2xy-y^2-x^2$ and factor that. Does that sound correct. Also I am not sure what to do for the projective?

Lastly if someone is familiar with M2 how would one input this and use Grobner basis to obtain the singularities.